# Pagination not displaying (its shows dimensions 659.08 x 0)

Tags: css, wordpress, pagination

I have created a Wordpress theme, where I have created a single.php for my blog posts. I had pagination, and everything was working fine before. Now It all of a sudden the pagination is not displayed on the page. When I 'inspect element' I can see that the code is there, but nothing is displayed. It says that the dimensions of the div is 659.08 x 0. I've searched the internet and It feels like I've tried everything. Do you have any suggestions as to what the problem can be? Here is a snippet of my code. Thanks in advance!

```
   <div class="container-fluid" id="content_container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <div class="inner">


             <p>By <?php the_author();?> | <?php the_date(); ?></p>
                         <?php the_content();
                 ?>

                    <div class="post-pag-wrap">
                        <div class="post-pag-container prev">
                            <?php previous_post_link('
                                <h6>%link</h6>
                                ', 'previous', false);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-pag-container next">
                              <?php next_post_link('
                                <h6>%link</h6>
                                ', 'next', false);
                            ?>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't write *which*  element has the dimensions 659.08 x 0, but this sounds very much like all its child elements are floated and the parent therefore doesn't have any height (because it doesn't wrap floated elements by default).

To avoid this, add `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` to that (parent) element. This should cause the element to wrap the floated children and make them visible that way.

Comment: ah sorry. Both div="post-pag-wrap'" and div class="post-pag-container next" and div class="post-pag-container previous" have dimensions 659.08 x 0

Comment: well, then try to add `overflow: auto` to `post-pag-container`... (and if that doesn't help try it also for `post-pag-wrap`

Comment: Well, since you didn't post your CSS it's hard to tell you anything more specific...

Comment: I deleted the css for the pagination, because I felt like I had to start from scratch, to figure out what the problem was  I am not sure which code would be relevant to post in this case. I will post some of the code in the question

Comment: There is too much css to post it here. Would it help if I gave you the Url to the site?

Comment: I can take a look, yes

Comment: Those two elements don't have *any*  content, they are empty. *Do* you have any other blog posts besides the one which is displayed on that page? If not, the links won't appear...

Comment: When I click your category links in the blog's sidebar, I get empty pages, so it seems you really don't have any other (public) posts... (If your posts aren't public yet, change their status)

Comment: Ahhh of course - I just had to ad more blogs :D Thanks! Now the pagination is there.